# need to write a formula that counts matches but also meets secondary criterion

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that counts matches from column C in "Archive" with "Document list" column A. I have it count total matches just fine. =COUNTIF(Archive!C:C,A:A)

I need to count only the matches where name in "Archive" column H  matches "Names" in column A.

Sample sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1befqsGQvbPfn0XTGrygLOGcrUIMrICUagJVH0S-2rDw/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: Why wouldn’t using `COUNTIFS` with a similar condition (replacing `C:C` in your example to `H:H`) solve the problem…? Am I missing something?

Comment: I am in the sample sheet right now

Comment: I’m not quite sure how that answers my question. Can you elaborate on what you’re trying to say?

Comment: My question was answered below. I was in the speadsheet answering questions.

Comment: would you wish for arrayformula solution?

Comment: @player0, yep....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would do it...

```
=countif(filter(Archive!C:C,isnumber(match(Archive!H:H,Names!$A$2:$A$7,0))),A2)
```

Answer (score 1):

arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 QUERY(Archive!C3:H, "select C,count(C) where H matches '"&
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Names!A2:A)&"' group by C"), 2, 0), 0)))
```

[image]